# Need help configuring NAT

Tags: vpn, nat, tunnel

First of all, the router I am using is a Cisco WRVS4400N.

My company runs a software which handles the MySQL database of all of their products.

The software now has an e-commerce module, so I have to set up a secure tunnel from our 
network to the server that will be hosting our e-commerce site so that when the database is updated, the site will also be updated.

The technician completeing the job said there is an IP conflict, and has asked me to NAT 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.115.0/24.

I am not really sure how to do this, and they want to charge $150 an hour to do it for me.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest to [have a look at the doc](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/wrvs4400n/administration/guide/WRVS4400N_AG_OL-20048.pdf)

Comment: I read the docs but I'm not really sure what I am looking for, what should I be searching for?

Comment: You should search for NAT

Answer (score 0):

QuinnFTW,

The technician with the NAT request needs to be more clear on what exactly needs to be done. From what I read in your question that does not sound like a proper NAT. Are these networks completely separate from each other? When you mentioned "secure tunnel" the first thing that came to mind was a site-to-site vpn tunnel which is completely different.

From a firewall perspective (assuming this is a static NAT rule we are talking about) there is a source (inside private address) and an public IP that is configured to use the "outside" interface. I have about 20 or so statics on my Cisco ASA so your mileage may vary.

In reference to the guide krisFR linked to I believe page 100 is what you might be looking for.

Good luck

Comment: The networks are completely separate.  I think the idea is that my server will trigger the event which causes the sync, so my firewall can remain closed while the other end is open.  I will look at what you suggested, thanks.